# Sort a Python list database

Tags: python, database, list, sorting, csv

The next code was modified to include a new menu item "(r)" to reorder the the names/numbers in a phone list saved a csv file. The steps included:

1. Adding two lines to the main_loop, one line to menu_choice to print out the new menu option (and add 'r' to the list of acceptable choices), and
2. A new function to do the reordering. This function was called `reorder_phones()`.

The file used to run this code is similar to the one below.

> ```
> Before:
> Choice: s
>      Name                     Phone Number 
>      1  Jerry Lopez             (212) 842-2527
>      2  George Sierr            (212) 452-8145
>      3  Elaine Benea            (212) 452-8723
> After:
> Choice: s
>      Name                     Phone Number 
>      1  Elaine Benea            (212) 452-8723
>      2  George Sierr            (212) 452-8145
>      3  Jerry Lopez             (212) 842-2527
> ```

The main problem  is that I am not sure how to save and use the sorted list; if anyone can guide me I will appreciate it.

```
import os
import csv


phones = []
name_pos = 0
phone_pos = 1
phone_header = [ 'Name', 'Phone Number']

def proper_menu_choice(which):
    if not which.isdigit():
        print ("'" + which + "' needs to be the number of a phone!")
        return False
    which = int(which)
    if which < 1 or which > len(phones):
        print ("'" + str(which) + "' needs to be the number of a phone!")
        return False
    return True

def delete_phone(which):
    if not proper_menu_choice(which):
        return
    which = int(which)

    del phones[which-1]
    print( "Deleted phone #", which)

def edit_phone(which):
    if not proper_menu_choice(which):
        return
    which = int(which)

    phone = phones[which-1]
    print("Enter the data for a new phone. Press <enter> to leave unchanged.")

    print(phone[name_pos])
    newname = input("Enter phone name to change or press return: ")
    if newname == "":
        newname = phone[name_pos]

    print(phone[phone_pos])    
    newphone_num = input("Enter new phone number to change or press return: ")
    if newphone_num == "":
        newphone_num = phone[phone_pos]

    phone = [newname, newphone_num]
    phones[which-1] = phone


def save_phone_list():

    f = open("myphones.csv", 'w', newline='')
    for item in phones:
        csv.writer(f).writerow(item)
    f.close()

def load_phone_list():
    if os.access("myphones.csv",os.F_OK):
        f = open("myphones.csv")
        for row in csv.reader(f):
            phones.append(row)
        f.close()

def show_phones():
    show_phone(phone_header, "")
    index = 1
    for phone in phones:
        show_phone(phone, index)
        index = index + 1
    print()

def show_phone(phone, index):
    outputstr = "{0:>3}  {1:<20}  {2:>16}"
    print(outputstr.format(index, phone[name_pos], phone[phone_pos]))

def create_phone():
    print("Enter the data for a new phone:")
    newname = input("Enter name: ")
    newphone_num = input("Enter phone number: ")
    phone = [newname,newphone_num]
    phones.append(phone)

def reorder_phones():
    global phones       # this insures that we use the one at the top
    sorted(phones, key=lambda x: x[0])

def menu_choice():
    """ Find out what the user wants to do next. """
    print("Choose one of the following options?")
    print("   s) Show")
    print("   n) New")
    print("   d) Delete")
    print("   e) Edit")
    print("   q) Quit")
    print("   r) Reorder")
    choice = input("Choice: ")    
    if choice.lower() in ['n','d', 's','e', 'q', 'r']:
        return choice.lower()
    else:
        print(choice +"?")
        print("Invalid option")
        return None


def main_loop():

    load_phone_list()

    while True:
        choice = menu_choice()
        if choice == None:
            continue
        if choice == 'q':
            print( "Exiting...")
            break     # jump out of while loop
        elif choice == 'n':
            create_phone()
        elif choice == 'd':
            which = input("Which item do you want to delete? ")
            print("which is ", which)
            delete_phone(which)
        elif choice == 's':
            show_phones()
        elif choice == 'e':
            which = input("Which item do you want to edit? ")
            print("which is ", which)
            edit_phone(which)
        elif choice == 'r':
            reorder_phones()
        else:
            print("Invalid choice.")

    save_phone_list()


# The following makes this program start running at main_loop() 
# when executed as a stand-alone program.    
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main_loop()
```

Comment: What does this line do - ```save_phone_list()``` ??

Comment: You should trim the parts of your code that you're not asking about. Please read the instructions: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: I included all the code in case another part of the code needs to be change! But essentially the line that needs attention is: 
def reorder_phones():
    global phones       # this insures that we use the one at the top
    sorted(phones, key=lambda x: x[0])

Comment: `sorted` returns a new list, which you aren't capturing, and the function exists and returns `None`. You can either `return sorted(...` or sort the list in-place using `my_list.sort()`

Comment: BTW your use of `global` is unnecessary.

Comment: Thanks  juanpa.arrivillaga, now I understand better!

Answer (score 0):

Use the following method to sort as the `sort()` function sorts the original file and `sorted()` sorts the result.

```
def reorder_phones():
    global phones       # this insures that we use the one at the top
    phones.sort()
```